# To configure JQuery Price-Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

At the moment I am using jQuery UI's slider to allow people to select a price range. The problem is, the slider is to small and needs to compensate for the minimum of 1 Euros and the maximum of 6000 Euros. The proposed solution is to use a small increment, maybe multiple of 25 till 400 euros and then rise exponentially like 500, 750, 1000 and then all the way upto maximum price available.

I've already created this kind of slider but I am using static values (Please see attached code) but the problem is When there any product where maximumprice range is 400, all these below value still shows up on slider.
Will appreciate your help..

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.priceSlider = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            setRedirect: false //redirect false for mobile version
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var $slider = jQuery(this),
                minPrice = Number($slider.attr('data-min')),
                maxPrice = Number($slider.attr('data-max')),
                valueMin = Number($slider.attr('data-valueMin')),
                valueMax = Number($slider.attr('data-valueMax')),
                inputMin = $slider.siblings('span[data-from]'),
                inputMax = $slider.siblings('span[data-to]'),
                requestUrl = $slider.attr('data-request'),
                redirect = settings.setRedirect;

            inputMin.text(valueMin);
            inputMax.text(valueMax);

            var submitButton = jQuery('.off-canvas-navigation .button-container #button-apply-filter');
            var clearAllButton = jQuery('.off-canvas-navigation .button-container #button-remove-filter');


            // var range = getRange;
            var rangeOne = {
                'min': [minPrice],
                '5%': 25,
                '10%': 50,
                '15%': 75,
                '20%': 100,
                '25%': 125,
                '30%': 150,
                '35%': 175,
                '40%': 200,
                '45%': 225,
                '50%': 250,
                '55%': 275,
                '60%': 300,
                '62.5%': 325,
                '65%': 350,
                '67.5%': 375,
                '70%': 400,
                '72.5%': 500,
                '75%': 600,
                '77.5%': 700,
                '80%': 800,
                '85%': 900,
                '90%': 1000,
                'max': [maxPrice]
            };
            var rangeTwo = {
                'min': [minPrice],
                '6%': 25,
                '12%': 50,
                '18%': 75,
                '24%': 100,
                '30%': 125,
                '36%': 150,
                '42%': 175,
                '48%': 200,
                '54%': 225,
                '60%': 250,
                '66%': 275,
                '72%': 300,
                '78%': 325,
                '84%': 350,
                '90%': 375,
                'max': [maxPrice],
            }

            function getRange(valueMax) {
                if (valueMax >= 400) {
                    return rangeOne;
                } else {
                    return rangeTwo;
                }
            }


            $slider.noUiSlider({
                start: [valueMin, valueMax],
                connect: true,
                snap: true,
                behaviour: 'drag',
                //step: 25,
                range: getRange(valueMax)
            }).on({
                    slide: function (e, values) {
                        if (values == undefined) {
                            var values = [];
                            values[0] = minPrice;
                            values[1] = maxPrice;
                        }
                        inputMin.text(Math.round(values[0]));
                        inputMax.text(Math.round(values[1]));

                    },
                    change: function (e, values) {
                        if (values == undefined) {
                            var values = [];
                            values[0] = minPrice;
                            values[1] = maxPrice;
                        }
                        submitButton.removeClass('inactive');
                        clearAllButton.removeClass('inactive');

                        var minValue = Math.round(values[0]),
                            maxValue = Math.round(values[1]);

                        if (redirect == true) {
                            window.location = requestUrl.replace('%minPrice%', minValue).replace('%maxPrice%', maxValue) + '#main';
                        }
                        else {
                            submitButton.attr('data-request', requestUrl.replace('%minPrice%', minValue).replace('%maxPrice%', maxValue));

                            if (!clearAllButton.hasClass('inactive')) {
                                clearAllButton.on('click', function (e) {
                                    $slider.find('.noUi-origin.noUi-connect').css('left', '0%');
                                    $slider.find('.noUi-origin.noUi-background').css('left', '100%');
                                    $slider.attr('data-valueMin', minPrice).attr('data-valueMax', maxPrice);
                                    $slider.trigger('slide').trigger('change');
                                    clearAllButton.addClass('inactive');
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Price Slider should use a small increment, maybe multiple of 25 till 400 euros and then rise exponentially like 500, 750, 1000 and then all the way upto maximum price available

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery UI's slider like(Edit: with range):

```js
var sliderArray = [ 1,25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000 ];

var sliderConfig = {
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: sliderArray.length - 1,
  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#sliderValueFrom').val( sliderArray[ ui.values[0] ]);
    $('#sliderValueTo').val( sliderArray[ ui.values[1] ]);
  },
  create: function() {
    $(this).slider('values',0,0);
    $(this).slider('values',1,sliderArray.length - 1);
  }
};

$('#sliderId').slider(sliderConfig);
```

```css
* {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:25px;
}
body {
    padding:25px;
}
#sliderId { margin:25px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<div id="sliderId"></div>

<input type="text" name="sliderValue" id="sliderValueFrom" value="" placeholder="Slider Value From" />
<input type="text" name="sliderValue" id="sliderValueTo" value="" placeholder="Slider Value To" />
```

Comment: thank you for your help.. but according to your code price is increasing in a linear fashion like 250, 500, 750, 1000 and so on..and also they are using same area on slider. these both conditions doesn't satisfy my conditions.
I need to satisfy two things
1)Price should increase exponentially and in non linear fashion like 
 a) < $400 : 1, 25 ,75, 100, 125, 150...400 : 25 Steps and should cover 50 percent of whole slider
 b) 401 -1000: 400, 500, 600...1000: 100 Steps and should cover 25 percent of whole slider

Comment: c) > $1000: 1000, 2000, 3000... : 1000 Steps and should cover remaining 25 percent of whole slider

Comment: I edit my answer, please see it now, sorry first time i didn't get your question properly. thanks

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for your help. Should I delete function getRange() from original code. How can I integrate your version in my code. Sorry I'm kinda newb in programming.

Comment: do you need the range slider?

Comment: @Vin Dev I edit my answer again with range, I think you can integrate now, if you face any problem please inform me